# Finding all solutions to congruence equation

Tags: congruences

my math professor gave us the following question on a past quiz and I didn't get it right and now I want to know how to do it:

```
 Find all the solutions to the congruence x^2 is equivalent to 1 mod 437 where
 mod 437=19*23.
```

I know I have to use the Chinese remainder theorem somewhere, but I'm not quite sure where that comes in...

If someone could give me a step by step walk through on how to do this problem, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it. It does take advantage of the structure of the problem, meaning it won't apply to all problems of this nature. In this problem, the Chinese Remainder Theorem boils down to the statement:

$x \equiv 1 \mod 437 \iff x \equiv 1 \mod 19 \text{ and } x \equiv 1 \mod 23$.

Now, how does this pertain to your question? Well,
\begin{align*}
 x^{2} \equiv 1 \mod 437 &\iff x^{2}-1 \equiv 0 \mod 437 \\
                         &\iff (x-1)(x+1) \equiv 0 \mod 437 \\
                         &\iff (x-1)(x+1) \equiv 0 \mod 19 \\
&\hspace{18pt}\text{ and } (x-1)(x+1) \equiv 0 \mod 23
\end{align*}
From here, there are four combinations that might work: $x$ is congruent to:

- 1 mod 19 and 1 mod 23
- 1 mod 19 and 22 mod 23
- 18 mod 19 and 1 mod 23
- 18 mod 19 and 22 mod 23

From there, you can find four answers mod 437. Knowing that's the only four answers is a different story, though.

Comment: I was under the impression that for a polynominal of degree n in a field, there will be n answers. So, doesn't that mean that since the power of the exponent in the problem is 2, there will be only 2 possible answers?

Comment: also, what are the 4 answers that work? I am having trouble going from the combinations that you got to the answer.

Comment: 1. Yes, but the number system you're working with isn't a field. Notably, numbers like 19, 38, 57, ... or 23, 46, etc don't have a multiplicative inverse (i.e. there's no number in mod 437 so that when you multiply 19 by it, you get 1). So you're not working in a field.

Comment: 2. This isn't too hard to figure out on your own. The two obvious answers the 1st and 4th: 1 and 436. The other two you can get by trial and error: for the 2nd answer, check the numbers that are 1 mod 19: 1, 20, 39, 58, 77, ... until you hit one that is 22 mod 23. Similar process for the third one.

Comment: Okay, thank you. One could say that modular arithmetic is not my strong suit.

Comment: It's certainly unintuitive, and will take some practice before you're comfortable with it. Problems like these will help.